# error: request for member data in something not a structure or union despite using arrow operator

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-declaration, member-access

I am facing an error: request for member data in something not a structure or union. I am passing the address of a structure `receiver_data` in a structure `global_vals` to a function in another file.

The `init_func` function receives the address as a pointer. I used the arrow operator since its a pointer but I cant seem to access the structure. Both memory addresses `&val.receiver_data` and `*ptr` are the same so I'm not quite sure where went wrong

Would appreciate if someone can point out my mistake.

The components are split across various source/ header files with the following structure.

- main.c
- func_init.c
- datatypes.c

main.c

```
global_vals val;
void main(void)
{
    val.receiver_data.data = 10;
    init_func(&val.receiver_data);
}
```

func_init.c

```
void init_func(int *ptr_data)
{
    printf("%d\n", ptr_data->data);
}
```

datatypes.h

```
typedef struct Receiver {
    int data;
} Receiver;
    
typedef struct {
    Receiver receiver_data;
    // truncated
} global_vals;
```

Comment: As far as I know, `int* ptr_data` cannot have any members, like `->data`. It's an integer.

Comment: Should be `void init_func(Receiver *ptr_data)`

Comment: That you don't get more compiler messages is because you don't declare the `init_func` function before you call it. If you did then you would be getting messages that you try to pass invalid arguments to the function. Always make it a habit to declare the functions you call, before you call them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Or, you know, simply don't use a compiler which hasn't been updated in the past 22 years... implicit function declarations were removed from the C language during the previous millennium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function parameter

```
void init_func(int *ptr_data)
{
    printf("%d\n", ptr_data->data);
}
```

has the type `int *` that is it is a pointer to a scalar object. So this construction `ptr_data->data` is invalid because integers do not have data members like `data`.

It is not clear why the function is not declared like

```
void init_func( Receiver *ptr_data);
```

An alternative approach is to declare and define the function like

```
void init_func(int *ptr_data)
{
    printf("%d\n", *ptr_data);
}
```

and call it like

```
init_func(&val.receiver_data.data);
```

I hope that actually the function does something useful instead of just outputting an integer.

Answer (score 0):

- The compiler says:

> error: request for member 'data' in something not a structure or union

- The compiler points at the exact location of the bug:

  ```
  |     printf("%d\n", ptr_data->data);
  |                            ^~
  ```
- The programmer thinks: Is `ptr_data` really a structure or union?
- The programmer checks the declaration `int *ptr_data`. No, it is not.